# Excel VBA - Code that does not autofill entire table column with the same formula

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am working with a table object and I need code to sort through column 3 and change any occurance where the date (mmm-d) is reading "Jan-0." Because I am working with a table object, every time I try to reference column "Clock Out" (E), which is formatted as such:

m/d/yyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM,

with a .formulaR1C1 piece of code, it changes each cell in column 3 to that formula. This is a problem because I would like column C (Date) to be determined by the value in column D (Clock In), or, if column D is empty, then I would like it to be populated by the value in Column E (Clock Out).

There are no occurrences where both Column D and Column E are empty.

```
currentSht.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(erow, ecol)), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
Set lst = currentSht.ListObjects("Table1")
lst.ListColumns.Add Position:=3
currentSht.Range("C2").Value = "=TEXT([@[Entry Time]],""mmm-d"")"

lstHeaders = Array("", "ID", "Agent Name", "Date", "Clock In", "Clock Out")
For i = 1 To 5
lst.ListColumns(i).Name = lstHeaders(i)
Next i

***Concerning portion of code***
For i = erow to 1 step -1
    if cells(i,3).TEXT = "Jan-0" Then
        cells(i,3).Value = "=([@[Clock Out]],""mmm-d"")"
    end if
next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, this did the trick:

```
For i = erow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 3).Text = "Jan-0" Then
       Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False '<~~ THIS LINE DID IT 
       Cells(i, 3).Value = "=TEXT([@[Clock Out]],""mmm-d"")"
    End If
Next i
```